# M1 Mac (Monterey 12.4) Touch ID is not working for sudo

Tags: terminal, password, sudo, touch-id, authentication

I followed [this set of instructions] for adding Touch ID authentication to `sudo`, but it's not working. Almost all the post/questions I found on the internet was more or less same and also they were almost 1 year old (June 2022).

Is this because Apple removed the feature or something?

Here's my `/etc/pam.d/sudo`

```
# sudo: auth account password session
auth       sufficient     pam_tid.so
auth       sufficient     pam_smartcard.so
auth       required       pam_opendirectory.so
account    required       pam_permit.so
password   required       pam_deny.so
session    required       pam_permit.so
```

Comment: Can you access /etc/pam.d directory when your are logged as the user who wants to sudo ?

Comment: Yes, I can. But this user only have read access

Comment: Does he have execute access (x) ?

Comment: Yes, that user has execute access to ```/etc/pam.d``` dir.
https://pasteboard.co/o4zQL3fJjTXV.png

Comment: Did you see [this](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253631751) ?

Comment: Yes, it did worked! And I was using tmux and I saw that to use it with tmux I would have to do some extra work. 
But all over it's working now!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `tmux`, you would need to set up [pam_reattach](https://github.com/fabianishere/pam_reattach) for it to work.

Comment: Yes, I did that.and it's working now